# Making panel at the top disappear after sliding up in Umano SlidingUpPanel

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Umano SlidingUpPanel library(https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) for my app and it fits pretty well. However, after sliding the [panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlQ2b.jpg) up, it moves to the [top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFVDx.jpg) of the page(by default). Is there any way of making the panel at the top completely disappear after sliding it up from the bottom of the first view?

Comment: With "panel at the top" do you mean the status bar (where the notifications are displayed) ?

Comment: @drilonreqica I've added the photos of the first view and the view after sliding up in the post. You can see the pictures by clicking on "panel" and on "top" words highlighted in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation of the AndroidSlidingUpPanel the simplest solution would be to listen to PanelState change and when it is expanded set the visibility of the panel you want not visible to GONE and vice-versa.

Here is the code:

```
slidingPanelLayout = (SlidingUpPanelLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);
slidingPanelLayout.addPanelSlideListener(new PanelSlideListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPanelSlide(View panel, float slideOffset) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPanelStateChanged(View panel, PanelState previousState, PanelState newState) {
            if (newState == PanelState.EXPANDED) {
                //here you can set the visibility of the panel you want to hide to GONE
            } else {
                //and here you would set the panel to VISIBLE again
            }
        }
    });
```

Also one more tip from me would be to use the BottomSheetDialogFragment which is a native android solution for this kind of use-cases.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialogFragment

https://medium.com/@kosta.palash/using-bottomsheetdialogfragment-with-material-design-guideline-f9814c39b9fc

Comment: Good I could help. Would you please accept my answer as the accepted answer :)

Comment: Yeah sure! Would be grateful if you also voted my question like so.